# Adding value to another database table while in an other controller is adding a new item

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

After saving data from the chats controller to the chat model, I want to add the last id of this chat item to another database table called issues. I do this from the ChatsController:

```
        // Get last inserted id from Chat
        $lastid = $this->Chat->getLastInsertId();
        // Set the issue id to be updated
        $this->Chat->Issue->id = $issueid;
        // Update Issue table
        $this->Chat->Issue->saveField('chat_id', $lastid);
```

Where I want to update Issue database item with id $issueid and add $lastid to field Issue.chat_id. $issueid is set before and is present and I am assuming $lastid is also set.

In both the issue and chat model, the models are belonging to the other.

What am I doing wrong that a new line is inserted in the issue database table instead of updating the correct one?

Comment: you sure `$issueid` is set to an already existing id in the `Issues` table?

Comment: Yes, the function is called using the issueid:

    public function view_issue($issueid) {
    } and to add the item to the Chat database table it is set correctly

Comment: Try switching your save to use the save() method instead - might show whether it's an issue of the use of the saveField() method or the value of the $issueid